# SQL Server replacing null with empty string

Tags: sql-server

I need to know what SQL statement do I use to produce an output where if a cell contains null then it pulls the information from the column next to it.

To explain better: I have three tables, table 1 contains 7 columns, table 2 contains 6 columns, table 3 contains 4 columns.

I need select 1 column from table 1 followed by a dash then select 3 columns from another table followed by a dash and then another column from a different table,but where ever a column contains null, the values must be replaced by a dash '-'.

This is the code I have so far :

```
SELECT 
    Episode_Name, '-', Pnr_FName, Pnr_LName, Guest, '-', Car_Make
FROM 
    EPISODES, PRESENTERS, CARS
```

I did try:

```
(CASE WHEN Guest = null THEN ''
END EPISODE)
```

and I bound it in the `select` statement but it did not work.

Any help would be appreciated! thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check a column value for `NULL` using the `=` operator, because the result will also be `NULL`.  Instead, you should use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.  But for readability purposes, I would use `COALESCE` instead of `CASE` statements.

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(Episode_Name, ' '),
              '-',
              COALESCE(Pnr_FName, ' '),
              COALESCE(Pnr_LName, ' '),
              COALESCE(Guest, ' '),
              '-',
              COALESCE(Car_Make, ' '))
FROM EPISODES, PRESENTERS, CARS
```

By the way, you should use explicit join syntax instead of using commas in the `FROM` clause, e.g.

```
FROM EPISODES e INNER JOIN PRESENTERS p
    ON e.col = p.col
```

Answer (score 0):

> I did try : (CASE WHEN Guest = null THEN '' END EPISODE)

try

```
case when guest is null then '' end
```

You can't compare nulls,to check if nulls are present ,you have to use `IS NULL`..